# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (anonymous function)

Tags: reactjs

I am getting a TypeError on the following statement:

```js
    let uploadSignal = true;
    
    mandatoryFields.forEach((element) => {
        let field = this.state[element];
        if(field.value === ""){
            field.error = "Required!";
            uploadSignal = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear that `field` is `undefined`.  Which means `this.state[element]` is `undefined`.  Are you asking how to check if a value is `undefined` before trying to use it?  Or are you asking why your value is `undefined`?  Or something else?

Comment: i am asking why value is undefined and how to solve this error so that i can run my program

Comment: you need to share more pieces of your code, like `mandatoryFields` and your `state`, for someone provide useful insights about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This means that you are trying to refer to a property called `value` on an `undefined` object.  The only place you do that is here:

```
if(field.value === ""){
```

Which means `field` is undefined.  `field` is being set here:

```
let field = this.state[element];
```

Which means `this.state[element]` is `undefined`.

> i am asking why value is undefined and how to solve this error so that i can run my program

For the former, we can't know.  You'll need to debug and discover what your runtime values are and why you expect this value to be defined.  All we can say with certainty is that it's not.

For the latter, you can conditionally check if the value is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) before trying to use it:

```
if(field && field.value === ""){
```

In the event that `field` is `undefined` then the left side of the `&&` operation will be ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), which will cause the entire condition to be `false` without needing to evaluate the right ride of the `&&` operation.  With the condition being `false`, the `if` block isn't executed and the code continues.